# "The truth about" vs. "the truth on"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which preposition is correct here?

> 1. The truth about "Unlimited".
> 2. The truth on "Unlimited".

The meaning of the sentence is roughly, exposing the truth of a concept, for example "Unlimited".

Comment: ***about***  -- that's just about it.

Comment: Are *"the truth on unlimited"*, and *"the truth of unlimited"* considered grammatical?

Comment: They just fail to make sense to me. These may have been used in literature, but seem to be semantically wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me your use of "Unlimited" is ambiguous- Is it a company named "Unlimited"? Or do you mean the truth about the word 'unlimited'? (Note capitalization differences).  Or do you mean the truth about the concept of limitlessness.

It think in general ***the truth about*** is used when discussing truths about a tangible entities. So if it were the company "*Unlimited*" I'd use the ***the truth about***.

I typically use ***the truth on*** when discussing the less tangible: *The truth on whether John's actions today helped divert the disaster may never be known.*

Comment: Yes "unlimited" here in quotes is referring to the *concept of limitlessness*.

Comment: The tangible-intangible difference does not seem to be supported by usage examples from Google search.